# What is the difference between a set and a combination?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems that a set is just a combination of objects, where the combination itself is regarded as another object. Since the repetition of elements in a set is not allowed, a set is a combination without repetition. And since the order of elements in a set does not matter, a set is a combination and not a permutation.

So, if a set and a combination are not the same mathematical object, what is the difference between them?

Comment: what do you mean by combination?

Comment: A combination is a selection of objects.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: You may think of combination as an operation on a set of elements. A set is not a combination, a set is not an operation. A set is just a collection of elements.